# Proof by contradiction: $ A \subseteq A $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to proof by contradiction that $ A \subseteq A $; if  $ A \nsubseteq A $ then $ \exists x \in A ( x \notin A ) $ but $ \exists x \in A ( x \notin A ) $ is contradiction (in fact: $ \exists x  ( x \in A \wedge x \notin A ) $) therefore $ A \subseteq A $ is true... The process is correct? Thank you all in advance

Comment: Yes, this is fine.

Comment: Yes its correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, the way I would write it is as follows:

Suppose there exists a set $A$ such that $A \nsubseteq A$. Then there exists $x \in A$ such that $x \notin A$. But $x \in A$, contradiction. Hence $A \subseteq A$.

The extra formalism isn't necessary unless you are trying to get a better understanding of using the quantifiers, which in this case you have used correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine but it is better you clarify both $A$  as $$A_1\subseteq A_2$$ where $A_1=A_2=A$.

Comment: I don't think I agree. This just encourages you to believe that things are different when they are actually the same. The contradiction is clearer if you write "$x\in A$ and $x\notin A$" than if you write "$x\in A_1$, $x\notin A_2$ and $A_1=A_2$". But maybe there are other reasons to prefer this notation.

Comment: @MattPressland: I know it might make some points you noted but if I wanted to prove like the OP did, I would prefered student find out what $A$ I mean when I write $x\in A$, the first $A$ or the second one. However, they both are the same.

Comment: That is also reasonable. My feeling to a degree though is that the contradiction arises from the fact that when you write $x\in A$, you can't tell "which $A$" you mean - you have to mean both - so you can't possibly also have $x\notin A$.

Comment: @MattPressland: Sometimes, I feel need a blackboard here to say what I mean.

Comment: It's fine, this is just a semantic argument anyway. Different people will find different notation clearer.

Comment: @MattPressland: Thank you for your kind suggestions. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Nice thought +1